# Uploading Files with 2 input

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter, upload

I want to upload Files with 2 Input file. first input just 1 File, and second multiple file. first input save to "./asset/sopic" and second save to "./asset/sdpic".
Here is My code (View):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Photo</label>
           <table frame="box">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url()."asset/sopic/default.png"; ?>" alt="..." id="foto" class="img-responsive center-block">
                      <input name="foto" type="file" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Masukkan Gambar" accept="image/*" onchange="readURL(this);">
                  </td>
                 </tr>
               </table>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label><span title="To select multiple image press 'CTRL' or 'SHIFT'." style="cursor: help;">Detailed Photo <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i></span></label>
                  <input type="file" name="file[]" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Masukkan Gambar" accept="image/*" multiple>
                 </div>
                </div>
```

and this the model:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './asset/sopic/'; //On "sopic" upload
                                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jfif|jpg|jpeg|png|gif'; //Pitcure Only
                                    $config['max_size'] = '2048'; //2MB
                                    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
                                    //$config['file_name'] = $prna; //set new Name
                                    $this->load->library('upload', $config); //load library upload

                                    $id = $this->loginm->getshopid(array("nama" => $nam), array("exp" => $dat));

                                    //Photos is detected OK
                                    if ($this->upload->do_upload('foto')){
                                        //Get Filename
                                        $fnm = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                                        chmod('./asset/sopic/'.$fnm, 0777);
                                        //Update user table on "Photo" column where Mail as ID
                                        $this->loginm->upvo(array('by_user' => $mail), array('kode' => $kod), array('photo' => $fnm));

                                        $errmsg[] = array('ico' => 'ti-check', 'txt' => '<b>OK: Shop Photo </b><br><i>'.$tus.' added!</b>',
                                            'typ' => 'success');
                                    }else{
                                        $errmsg[] = array('ico' => 'ti-info', 'txt' => '<b>Info: </b><br><i>'.$this->upload->display_errors().'</b>',
                                            'typ' => 'warning');
                                    }

                                    if(!empty($fpi)){
                                        $x = 0;
                                        foreach($fpi as $gam){
                                            $x++;
                                            if($this->upload->do_upload($gam)){
                                                //Get Filename
                                                $fnm = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                                                chmod('./asset/sdpic/'.$fnm, 0777);
                                                //Update user table on "Photo" column where Mail as ID
                                                $this->loginm->upvo(array('by_user' => $mail), array('kode' => $kod), array('photo' => $fnm));
                                            }else{
                                                $errmsg[] = array('ico' => 'ti-info', 'txt' => "<b>Info: Photo $x</b><br><i> :: ".$this->upload->display_errors().'</b>',
                                                    'typ' => 'warning');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        $errmsg[] = array('ico' => 'ti-info', 'txt' => "<b>Info: </b<i>No Detail Pitcures Selected</i>",
                                                    'typ' => 'warning');
                                    }
```

But i'm trying to upload always show Error "File Not support".

Comment: what is there in $fpi array?

Comment: $fpi is from file
$fpi = $this->input->post("file", TRUE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your foreach loop code with following.

```
    $files = $_FILES['file'];
    if(!empty($files['name'])){
        foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $gam){
            $_FILES['images[]']['name']= $files['name'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['type']= $files['type'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['tmp_name']= $files['tmp_name'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['error']= $files['error'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['size']= $files['size'][$key];
            if($this->upload->do_upload('images[]')){
                //Get Filename
                $fnm = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                chmod('./asset/sdpic/'.$fnm, 0777);
                //Update user table on "Photo" column where Mail as ID
                $this->loginm->upvo(array('by_user' => $mail), array('kode' => $kod), array('photo' => $fnm));
            }else{
                $errmsg[] = array('ico' => 'ti-info', 'txt' => "<b>Info: Photo $x</b><br><i> :: ".$this->upload->display_errors().'</b>',
                    'typ' => 'warning');
            }
        }
    }else{
        $errmsg[] = array('ico' => 'ti-info', 'txt' => "<b>Info: </b<i>No Detail Pitcures Selected</i>",
                    'typ' => 'warning');
    }
```

Comment: what is variable $key from?